# Is this more efficient?

Tags: ruby, memory-efficient

My situation does not accept reading a whole file in memory and then process it. I have this piece of code that reads a file as much as is extracted without putting the whole file in memory.

```
def load_yaml_from_gz(gz)
  loaded = nil
  Zlib::GzipReader.open(gz) do |f|
    # patch needed as YAML wants to know encoding
    # see https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/105
    class << f
      def external_encoding
        Encoding::UTF_8
      end
    end
    loaded = YAML.load(f, gz)
  end
  return loaded
end
```

Any idea how I can measure memory efficiency of this design versus efficiency of reading the whole file and loading into YAML?

Comment: You seem to imply that one cannot read a text file line-by-line in Ruby.  Line-by-line is probably the most common way of reading a text file. See docs for the classes [IO](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/IO.html) and  [File](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/File.html).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I don't see why you read my message like that. I'm actually concerned if `Psych` does actually read `io` objects in chunks or internally reads the whole thing to memory, then process. It is strange `Psych` API is not well documented for reading `io`. Either I missed something or it is not documented, but I had to look at source to see that this is possible (and how to do it).